# How to set width of DataTables?

Tags: jquery, css, datatables

I can't seem to find anything in the documents that sets the total size of the DataTable.

I've tried `style='width: x%'` but that doesn't move the search, pagination, or the other things

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the DataTable expands to the whole width of its parent, you could try to put the DataTable in a `<div style="width: 50% !important"></div>`